# I would like to force Hover on a specific section of my website or find a way around

Tags: css, wordpress, hover

I'm having a trouble with a wordpress theme and a client.
I have a 4 columns in this section with same images. The client wants different images on each column, wordpress allows me to do that but only if I hover the element.
I would like to find a way to make appear those different images on each column without having to hover it.
Thanks a lot

The section I need help
[image: The section I need help]

Wordpress personnalisation

[image: wordpress personnalisation]

Comment: Do you have a live demo somewhere we could check ?

Comment: I doubt anyone here knows what this "Feature" element is, likely that is something provided by the specific theme. So you will probably need to overwrite or modify the corresponding template file ...

Comment: @MaxiGui yes here is the live demo
http://demo.justfreewpthemes.com/?theme=aravalli&_ga=2.48367462.136398874.1651064495-932520715.1651064495
the section name is "features"

Comment: you can easely play with css `opacity` to get something like this: https://ibb.co/1vSk1gK

Comment: You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.